# How to Convert very large Decimal number to Factorial number system?

Tags: c++, algorithm, permutation, combinatorics, number-systems

I want to convert decimal number to   Factorial number system.

I want to do this for finding nth Lexicographic permutation of array up to 100 elements eg. A[87]={1,2,3..,87}

I am given index 'n' whose lexicographic permutation at that position I need to find. e.g 2nd permutation of {1,2,3} is {1,3,2}

For this I am trying to use Factorial number system.

The below link gives information about conversion method.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factorial_number_system

As explained (463) in decimal gives 341010! in factorial.

463 ÷ 1 = 463, remainder 0

463 ÷ 2 = 231, remainder 1

231 ÷ 3 = 77, remainder 0

77 ÷ 4 = 19, remainder 1

19 ÷ 5 = 3, remainder 4

3 ÷ 6 = 0, remainder 3

This method can be applied only if decimal number falls in permissible range like unsigned long long int.

What do to if number can't fit in integer range?

My test cases involves number so large that they need to be stored in string format.(e.g. Find 123456789012345678901234555623344 permutation of array[100]={1,2,3,4,....100})

I am trying to solve this problem in c++.

(Use of next_permutation() in c++ to get up to given index is costly method and takes a lot of time.)

Comment: Try using __int128 or use GMP https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Multiple_Precision_Arithmetic_Library

Comment: Can't you make a function that divides an array by a number and returns you the quotient as an array (and remainder as a number)?

Comment: If you want, I can provide you with a function which can do it.

Comment: Yes. You can give the function. I am a beginner.

Comment: Ok. Give me a bit of time. I'm assuming you are familiar with STL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the code. You can see and ask me for any confusion.

Also, I have only one test case which you have provided and I have not done an exhaustive test of the code. If you find any error, I'll be happy to resolve.

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

#define MAX 1000000
#define MOD 1000000007
#define F first
#define S second
#define PB push_back
#define MP make_pair
#define V vector
#define I int
#define D double
#define B bool
#define pii pair<int,int>
#define LL long long

#define in(x) scanf("%d",&x)
#define in2(x,y) scanf("%d%d",&x,&y)
#define lin(x) scanf("%lld",&x)
#define lin2(x,y) scanf("%lld%lld",&x,&y)
#define FOR(i,a,b) for(i=a;i<b;i++)
#define all(v) v.begin(),v.end()

string q;    //this is the input
V<I> sol;    //this is final solution vector. (will be printed in reverse)

void divide(I n){    //function to divide a string by `n`
    string r = "";
    I i,k=0;
    FOR(i,0,q.length()){
        k *= 10;
        k += (q[i] - '0');
        I g = k / n;
        k = k % n;
        if((r.length()==0 && g!=0) || (r.length()>0)){
            r += (char)(g + '0');
        }
    }
    q = r;
    sol.PB(k);
}

I main(){
    cin>>q;
    I i;
    FOR(i,1,101){   //assuming 100 is the limit
        if(q.length()==0)
            break;
        divide(i);
    }
    //print the result
    for(i=sol.size()-1;i>=0;i--)
        //printf("%d ",sol[i]);
        cout<<sol[i]<<" ";
    printf("\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! It really helped to understand the technique.

Comment: sure...happy to help :)

Answer (score 0):

Although the title states that you are looking for a way to convert decimal numbers to integers, I will given an answer to the actual problem you're trying to solve: how to get the Kth permutation of an array of N elements.

Simply put, you need to go digit by digit in predicting the Kth permutation of the given array. The theoretical side of things are pretty simple. Assume that you have the elements in the array A and you store the information on whether each element is used in a second array S. S will be updated as you pick appropriate value for each digit. The result will be stored in an array R.

There are N! permutations of the elements in the given array A. For an array with N digits, let's consider how many permutations there are if the smallest element in A is picked to be the leftmost digit in the result, R[0]. It's (N-1)!, right? So permutations from #1 to #(N-1)! belong to the case where the leftmost element of the result is the smallest element in A. Permutations #((N-1)! + 1) to #(2 *(N-1)!) have second smallest value of A as R[0]. So permutations #((i-1) * (N-1)! + 1) to #(i * (N-1)!) uses ith unused and lexicographically-smallest digit in A as R[0].

In a more generalized sense, the value is being used in R[d] in the Kth lexicographically smallest permutation is A[i] such that A[i] is the ith lexicographically smallest element **that is not used so far** and such that (i * (N-1-d)! + 1) <= k **and** k <= ((i+1) * (N-1-d)!).

It will take **O(N)** time to find the suitable i value if you traverse the entire S. I am not sure as to how you may implement it exactly, but you may also be able to do binary search on S and achieve finding appropriate i in O(logN) time.

If you have large K values, I think that you will need to implement big integer multiplication in order to do the comparison, but I'll update this portion of the answer if I think of a clever way to get around this.

Once you pick the proper i, you can just assign A[i] as R[d] and go on to find the next digit.

Below is the piece of code that implements this solution. It is lengthy, but most of it is just the big integer implementation. The gist of the algorithm is actually less than 30 lines. I just wanted to provide a working code so that you may test it yourself if you'd like.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
#define NLIMIT 100
#define ASIZELIMIT 101
#define BIGINTBUCKETSLIMIT 100
#define BUCKETCAPACITY 1000000000
#define DIGITSPERBUCKET 9

using namespace std;

/* sufficient big integer implementation */
class BigInt
{
    /*
     * Note that BIGINTBUCKETSLIMIT should be high enough so that
     * the values given as input does not cause overflow
     * or access violation from the last bucket in operations
     * multiply and subtract.
     */
public:
    long long buckets[BIGINTBUCKETSLIMIT];

    BigInt() {
        for(int i=0; i < BIGINTBUCKETSLIMIT; ++i) {
            buckets[i] = 0LL;
        }
    }

    BigInt(int initialValue) {
        for(int i=0; i < BIGINTBUCKETSLIMIT; ++i)
        {
            buckets[i] = initialValue % BUCKETCAPACITY;
            initialValue /= BUCKETCAPACITY;
        }
    }

    void multiply(int val) {
        for(int i= BIGINTBUCKETSLIMIT - 1; i >= 0; --i)
            buckets[i] = buckets[i] * val;

        for(int i=0; i < BIGINTBUCKETSLIMIT - 1; ++i) {
            buckets[i+1] += buckets[i] / BUCKETCAPACITY;
            buckets[i] = buckets[i] % BUCKETCAPACITY;
        }
    }

    void subtract(BigInt B) {
        for(int i= 0; i < BIGINTBUCKETSLIMIT; ++i) {
            buckets[i] = buckets[i] - B.buckets[i];
            if(buckets[i] < 0LL) {
                buckets[i] += BUCKETCAPACITY;
                buckets[i+1]--;
            }
        }
    }

    const BigInt & operator=(const BigInt &B) {
        for(int i=0; i < BIGINTBUCKETSLIMIT; ++i)
            buckets[i] = B.buckets[i];
        return *this;
    }

    bool operator<(const BigInt &B) {
        for(int i=BIGINTBUCKETSLIMIT-1; i >= 0; --i)
            if(buckets[i] != B.buckets[i])
                return buckets[i] < B.buckets[i];
        return false;
    }

    void importFromStr(string &src)
    {
        long long buffer = 0, j = 0;
        for(int i=src.size() - 1; i >= 0; i -= DIGITSPERBUCKET) {
            buffer = 0;
            for(int k=max(0, i - DIGITSPERBUCKET + 1); k <= i; ++k) {
                buffer = buffer * 10 + (src[k] - '0');
            }
            buckets[j++] = buffer;
        }
    }
};

BigInt factorials[ASIZELIMIT];

void preprocessFactorials(int n)
{
    factorials[0] = BigInt(1);
    for(int i=1; i <= n; ++i) {
        factorials[i] = factorials[i-1];
        factorials[i].multiply(i);
    }
}

void findKthPermutation(int N, int A[], BigInt K, int result[]) {
    BigInt tmpBigInt;

    bool S[ASIZELIMIT];
    for(int i=0; i < N; ++i)
        S[i] = true;
    K.subtract(BigInt(1));
    preprocessFactorials(N);

    for(int d=0; d < N; ++d) {
        for(int i=0, j=0; i < N; ++i) {
            if(S[i]) {
                tmpBigInt = factorials[N-1-d];
                tmpBigInt.multiply(j+1);
                if(K < tmpBigInt) {
                    result[d] = A[i];
                    S[i] = 0;
                    tmpBigInt = factorials[N-1-d];
                    tmpBigInt.multiply(j);
                    K.subtract(tmpBigInt);
                    break;
                }
                ++j;
            }
        }
    }
}

int main() {
    string k;
    BigInt K;
    int N;
    int A[ASIZELIMIT], R[ASIZELIMIT];

    cin >> N >> k;
    for(int i=0; i < N; ++i)
        cin >> A[i];
    K.importFromStr(k);

    sort(A, A+N);
    findKthPermutation(N, A, K, R);

    cout << R[0];
    for(int i=1; i < N; ++i)
        cout << " " << R[i];
    cout << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

As you may easily observe the 2 loops in function findKthPermutation and my BigInt class, the implementation works in O(N<sup>3</sup>), regardless of K. Although I don't know your exact performance needs, as N <= 100, it may be efficient enough. If it is not as efficient as you desire, my first suggestion would be be optimizing storing the information in S using some other data structure that may yield in O(logN) time the appropriate i value sought for each digit d.

Finally, note that this solution assumes that A contains no duplicate elements, *as that meddles with the lexicographical enumeration of the possible permutations*.